# Как устроить несколько контейнеров Docker с двумя приложениями Node.js и базой данных к ним?

Tags: node.js, docker

Начал изучать докер контейнеры и хочу чтобы мне сказали, в чём я ошибаюсь.
Есть веб-приложение, которое включает в себя базу данных, парсер других сайтов и роутинг с раздачей API пользователям. Вопрос, правильно ли будет сделать три контейнера таким вот образом:

1. Будет база данных на порте 27017,
2. Одно Express приложение на порте 3000, которое подключится к базе данных на порте 27017, в котором будет только один роут для страницы парсинга `http://localhost:3000/parse` где будет кнопка "Начать парсинг", чтобы обновлять данные в бд, которая будет хостится. Некого рода админ панель.
3. Другое Express приложение на порте 5000, где будет роутинг для пользователей и и выдача данных пользователям через API, которые будут браться из базы на порту 27017

И собрать всё это дело через docker-compose.

Возмжно я неправильно понял концепцию, ибо информации не так уж и много, в основном все гайды заканчиваются тем, что подключается приложение и база данных в разных контейнерах, а примеров посложнее просто нет. Но на сколько я понял, в каждом контейнере хостится отдельное Node.js приложение, но все они на одном доменном имени общаются между собой на разных портах. Поправьте или дайте каких-то советов пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вполне рабочее решение. Если вы хотите чтобы у вас все было доступно по 80 порту, то вам необходимо поставить nginx и настроить маршруты. Например api.домен.ru будет ссылаться на 5000 порт, а просто домен.ru будет выдавать то что у вас на 3000 порту.

На мой взгляд, разделять на два приложения не стоит, так как тот функционал что вы описываете можно сделать в одном приложении. 
Для управления приложениями можете использовать http://pm2.keymetrics.io/